# Chrome extension private API?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

Hello I would like to use `networkingPrivate` api, which one is from chrome private API, I have added permission for networkingPrivate but it seems that is not enough. Also I found this

> These are only usable by extensions bundled with Chrome, they are not publicly accessible.

here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/private_apis, but I'm not sure what that exactly mean, and how to do that.

My original intention is to get info about wifi (ssid,...)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be a security risk to allow user extensions to access this information direct from the OS. I think the private API is for Chrome OS, so that you can access and modify OS features direct from the browser, since Chrome OS is basically just a browser.

You could try looking at [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging), which I believe will allow you to connect your extension to a native application installed on the host's machine. The application written by you would have some link between the extension, and then you can pass messages between the two. For example, your extension could request network information, and the native app will get that and send this information back to the extension.

I haven't looked into this so I may be wrong, but worth investigating. I'd be very interested to see the result.

Comment: Unfortunately native messaging is not support for chrome os, weird :) Now investigating native client, but it seems that data like wifi info is not available because it runs inside sendbox and have available resource as js, used only for performances.

Answer (score 0):

Private APIs are made for internally usage.
For example, DeveloperPrivate API is used on chrome://extensions page.

They have stronger power than other APIs. but they also have security issues if they are open.  if you really need to use them, just ask to make new API.